# Realm V10, How to persist authentication in React native

Tags: react-native, realm, mongodb-stitch

MongoDB Realm was recently launched, I am following the documentation for authentication but when I restart the application and re-enter the data (auth) does not persist, What could have happened??

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I am following the task tracker tutorial and it doesn't persist.
https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/react-native/